# Accessibility Callback - when talkback finish reading announcement

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

On some user action, I want to make some `announcement` on the screen and soon after, I want to shift accessibility focus on the `specifc view`.

I can achieve it like,

```
 view!!.announceForAccessibility("some action failed.")
  Handler().postDelayed({
         specificView.requestFocus() 
    specificView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
   }, 1000)
```

But this is just a workaround. It may fail in some case when a user has `customized speaking rate` etc.

> Is there any way where we can get a callback when talkback finish with reading announcement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a correct solution or not but this worked for me.

```
 specificView.contentDescriotion = "text you need to annonce"
 specificView.requestFocus()
 specificView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
 Handler().postDelayed({
     specificView.contentDescriotion = "actual content description for that view"
 }, 300)
```

Making an announcement to the content description for a view that you want to focus.